# 1d Array Transformation: Distributing groups of different sizes into unique batches with certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Problem: 
Create the *most efficient* function to turn 1d array (group_id column) into another 1d array (output column).

The conditions are:

1. At most `n` groups can be in any batch, in this example `n=2`.
2. Each batch must contain groups of the same size.
3. Trivial condition: minimise the number of batches.

The function will distribute these groups of different size into batches with unique identifiers, with the condition that each batch has a fixed size AND each batch contains only groups with the same size.

```
data = {'group_size': [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,1,1],
        'batch_id':   [1,4,6,1,4,6,7,8,2,5,2,3,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)

    group_size  batch_id
0          1       1
1          2       4
2          3       6
3          1       1
4          2       4
5          3       6
6          4       7
7          5       8
8          1       2
9          2       5
10         1       2
11         1       3
12         1       3
```

**What I need:**

`some_function( data['group_size'] )` to give me `data['batch_id']`

Edit:

**My Clumsy Function**

```
def generate_array():

    out = 1
    batch_size = 2
    dictionary = {}

    for i in range(df['group_size'].max()):
        # get the mini df corresponding to the group size
        sub_df = df[df['group_size'] == i+1 ]
        # how many batches will we create?
        no_of_new_batches = np.ceil ( sub_df.shape[0] / batch_size )
        # create new array
        a = np.repeat(np.arange(out, out+no_of_new_batches ), batch_size)
        shift = len(a) - sub_df.shape[0]

        # remove last elements from array to match the size
        if len(a) != sub_df.shape[0]:
            a = a[0:-shift]

        # update batch id
        out = out + no_of_new_batches

        # create dictionary to store idx
        indexes = sub_df.index.values

        d = dict(zip(indexes, a))

        dictionary.update(d)

    array = [dictionary[i] for i in range(len(dictionary))]

    return array

generate_array()
Out[78]:
[1.0, 4.0, 6.0, 1.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. I don't think it gives exactly the same result as your function, but it satisfies your three rules:

```
import numpy as np

def package(data, mxsz):
    idx = data.argsort()
    ds = data[idx]
    chng = np.empty((ds.size + 1,), bool)
    chng[0] = True
    chng[-1] = True
    chng[1:-1] = ds[1:] != ds[:-1]
    szs = np.diff(*np.where(chng))
    corr = (-szs) % mxsz
    result = np.empty_like(idx)
    result[idx] = (np.arange(idx.size) + corr.cumsum().repeat(szs)) // mxsz
    return result

data = np.random.randint(0, 4, (20,))
result = package(data, 3)
print(f'group_size {data}')
print(f'batch_id   {result}')
check = np.lexsort((data, result))
print('sorted:')
print(f'group_size {data[check]}')
print(f'batch_id   {result[check]}')
```

Sample run with n=3, the last two lines of the output are the same as the first two, only sorted for easier checking:

```
group_size [1 1 0 1 2 0 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 0 2 0]
batch_id   [3 3 1 3 6 1 6 5 6 7 2 5 7 5 2 1 2 0 4 0]
sorted:
group_size [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]
batch_id   [0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7]
```

How it works:

1) sort data

2) detect where sorted data change to identify groups of equal values ("groups of group sizes")

3) determine sizes of the groups of groups sizes and for each calculate what misses to a clean multiple of n

4) enumerate the sorted data while at each switch to a new group of group sizes jumping to the next clean multiple of n; we use (3) to do this in a vectorized fashion

5) floor divide by n to get the batch ids

6) shuffle back to original order